# KivyMD setting colors for hint_text, text, error_text do not seem to work

Tags: colors, kivy, kivymd, textinput

I have working code (using python 3.9, kivy 2.1.0, kivymd 1.1.1) but cannot get it to set any of the colors that are supposed to be settable via KV keywords from the KivyMD Documentation.

I have tried: line_color_focus, background_color, disabled_foreground_color, foreground_color, hint_text_color, and selection_color.  Are there any others to try?  I am really trying to get the hint text and input text to be black or white depending on background color.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

KV = '''
<IconListItem>
    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon

MDScreen:
    MDTextField:
        id: waveform
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .3, 'center_y': .6}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: "250dp"
        font_size: '25sp'
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
        required: True
        hint_text: "Wave Form"
        keyboard_mode: "managed"       
        on_focus: if self.focus: {app.open_menu(self, app.menu1), app.set_cust_labels()}

    MDTextField:
        id: freq1
        input_filter: "float"
        input_type: "number"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .3, 'center_y': .5}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: "250dp"
        font_size: '25sp'
        multiline: False
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
        required: True
        hint_text: "Start Frequency in Hz"
        helper_text: "Enter a number between .01 and 20000"
        helper_text_mode: "persistent"
        on_focus: if self.focus: app.set_cust_labels()


    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .55, 'center_y': .2}
        MDLabel:
            id: waveform_text
            valign: "center"
            font_size: '25sp'
            theme_text_color: "Primary"

        MDLabel:
            id: freq1_text
            valign: "center"
            font_size: '25sp'
            theme_text_color: "Primary"
'''

class IconListItem(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()

class Test(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)

        self.wf_list_items = ["Sine", "Rectangle", "Sawtooth", "Impulse", "Bemer"]

        menu_items_wf = [
            {
                "viewclass": "IconListItem",
                "icon": "account",
                "height": dp(56),
                "text": f"{self.wf_list_items[i]}",
                "on_release": lambda x=i: self.set_item_waveform(f"{self.wf_list_items[x]}"),
            } for i in range(5)]

        self.menu1 = MDDropdownMenu(
            items=menu_items_wf,
            position="auto",
            width_mult=3,
        )

    def set_item_waveform(self, text__item):
        self.screen.ids.waveform.text = text__item
        self.screen.ids.waveform.focus = False
        self.menu1.dismiss()

    def open_menu(self, textfield, menu):
        textfield.focus = True
        menu.width_mult = textfield.width / dp(55)
        menu.max_height = dp(300)
        menu.caller = textfield
        menu.open()
        textfield.focus = False

    def set_cust_labels(self):
        self.screen.ids.waveform_text.text = self.screen.ids.waveform.text
        self.screen.ids.freq1_text.text = self.screen.ids.freq1.text

    def build(self):
        return self.screen

Test().run()
```

Does anyone have some suggestions on how to set text color to black?  I have had no luck using any of the color settings in MDTextField.

```
line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1 <- in code doesn't work
background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
disabled_foreground_color: 0,0,0 1
foreground_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
hint_text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
selection_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Each of those do not seem to set any of the text items to black.  Any reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/textfield/#kivymd.uix.textfield.textfield.MDTextField.text_color_normal). The attributes for text color are `text_color_normal` and `text_color_focus`. Similarly, for hint text: `hint_text_color_normal` and `hint_text_color_focus`. The kivymd docs are a good source of that sort of information.

Comment: For some reason with the versions of KivyMD etc. I am unable to make that work.  I wonder if I am doing something wrong.  See the line I used to set color.  I have substituted ALL of them one at a time with NO VISIBLE CHANGE to the colors displayed.  Including: ```text_color_normal: 0,0,0,1 ```

Comment: Geeze.  It wasn't working before.  Heck if it's working correctly now.  I must have used "[0,0,0,1]" instead of 0,0,0,1.  Thank you.  Now to change the other colors.  I really did read the documentation SEVERAL times.  I missed those somehow.

Comment: The following is what worked.  Thanks @John Anderson. ```                    helper_text_color_normal: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    text_color_normal: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    hint_text_color_normal: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    hint_text_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    text_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
```